# is there a way to read the cumulative size of all files in a folder?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls

I want to read the size of a folder from the command line.  `ls -lh` shows all folders as being 4k, which presumably is the size of the footprint of the folder itself, rather than the contained files.  I would like to read the size of all contained files within the folder.  is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the du command:

```
du -sh foldername
```

Answer (score 4):

```
du -s folder
```

`-s` stands for summarize.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

> du -csh foldername/*

which gives file and folder sizes under "foldername" separately and the total size in last row.

Comment: The `-c` is helpful if you are selecting a subset of files in a folder.  For example, if you're trying to see how big your web assets are, you could use `du -csh folder/*.js` to measure only the JS files, omitting CSS and HTML.